# Proof of the equivalence of the Band-RMS evaluated in time and frequency

Tags: bandpass, periodogram, parseval

Ignoring normalization factors, we can define the squared Root Mean Square (RMS) of a discret-time signal $x[t+n], n=0,1,...$,  at time $t$ as:
$$\mathrm{RMS}^2_t  = \sum_{n=0} ^{N-1} |x[t+n]|^2$$
which, by virtue of the [Parseval's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parseval%27s_theorem#Notation_used_in_engineering), can be shown to be equivalent to its frequency-domain analogue:
\begin{equation}
\mathrm{RMS}^2_t  = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{k=0} ^{N-1} |X_t[k]|^2
\end{equation}
with $X_t[k]$ the signal [Discrete Fourier Transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform) evaluated at discrete times from $t$ to $t+N-1$:

$$ X_t[k] = \sum_{n=0} ^{N-1} x[t+n] e^{-2\pi i~\frac{kn}{N}}$$
times the irrelevant phase $e^{-2\pi i~kt/N}$. Then, the RMS can be seen as the frequency-integrated periodogram Power Spectral Density estimator:

$$\mathrm{RMS}^2_t  = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{k=0} ^{N-1} |X_t[k]|^2 =
\frac{1}{N}\sum_{k=0} ^{N-1} \left| \sum_{n=0} ^{N-1} x[t+n] e^{-2\pi i~\frac{kn}{N}}\right|^2 = \sum_{k=0} ^{N-1} \hat{P}_t[k]
$$

My question is: **can we prove a similar relation for the signal Band-RMS?**

We can directly define the Band-RMS (BRMS) in the frequency domain, sharply cutting the frequencies in the sum:

$$ \mathrm{BRMS}_t (k_1,k_2) = \sum _{k_1 \leq k \leq k_2} \hat{P}_t [k] $$

In the time domain, we can sum a band-passed version of the signal, $x_{(k_1,k_2)}[t]$, obtained convolving the signal with a bad-pass filter $w_{(k_1,k_2)}[t]$ with characteristic frequencies corresponding to $k_1$ and $k_2$:

$$x_{(k_1,k_2)}[t] = \big(x\ast w_{(k_1,k_2)}\big)[t]=\sum_{n=0} ^{N-1} w_{(k_1,k_2)}[n] x[t-n], \qquad \mathrm{BRMS} _t (k_1,k_2) = \sum _{n=0} ^{N-1} \big| x _{ (k_1,k_2) } [t+n] \big| ^2 $$

I have the feeling that this and the above definition of BRMS are equivalent, or at least approximately so. The difficulty that I have in proving this claim is that a sharp cut in the frequency implies a signal with infinite duration in time, and vice versa. So, I would need a windowed/filtered periodogram, corresponding to the band-passed signal in time.

Any idea how to formally prove the equivalence of the two BRMS definitions?

*Thanks!*

---

Partially related to [this other question](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/59451/parseval-for-a-continuos-but-limited-signal).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a Discrete Fourier Transform is used, the band select over an integer number of bins is not of infinite duration in time but circular over the finite time interval of $N$ samples as given by the Dirichlet Kernel (a time aliased Sinc function). Selecting a subset of the bins is identical in operation to zero padding a given set of bins, which is detailed at [this other post](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/83871/21048) which provides the formula for the Dirichlet Kernel when multiple bins are selected and further details the related convolution operation in time.

However I think the proof can be much simpler by following the original process: Given a selected band of samples from the frequency domain, we can compute the RMS in frequency, and by virtue of Parseval's theorem, the inverse Fourier Transform of those samples as a time domain waveform will have the same RMS result in time, as follows (also possibly incorrect normalization factors depending on how $X_t[k]$ is scaled):

$$\text{RMS}^2_{(k_1,k_2,t)}  = \frac{1}{k_2-k_1}\sum_{k=k_1} ^{k_2} |X_t[k]|^2$$

$$x_{(k_1,k_2,t)}[n] = \frac{1}{k_2-k_1}\sum_{k=k_1}^{k_2}X_t[k]e^{2\pi i kn/N}$$

We note that $x_{(k_1,k_2,t)}[n]$ will have $N$ samples regardless of how many samples in the DFT are zeroed.

B.V.O.P.T.:

$$\text{RMS}^2_{(k_1,k_2,t)} = \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} \bigg|x_{(k_1,k_2,t)}[n]\bigg|^2  $$

Resulting in:

$$\text{RMS}^2_{(k_1,k_2,t)} =  \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} \bigg|x_{(k_1,k_2,t)}[n]\bigg|^2 = \frac{1}{k_2-k_1}\sum_{n=0}^{N-1} \bigg| \sum_{k=k_1}^{k_2}X_t[k]e^{2\pi i kn/N} \bigg|^2 = \sum _{k_1 \leq k \leq k_2} \hat{P}_t [k] $$

(As mentioned a normalized factor may be missing, but this demonstrates the process.)

Comment: Thanks,  @dan-boschen . I agree that proving the equivalence from the frequency to the time domain is simpler and sufficiently convincing. This also has the advantage of not sticking to any specific filter $w$ that produces the band-pass in the time domain. Upvoted and accepted